Book about a new student in a cruel school
This novel was used as part of a UK secondary school lesson (or several lessons?) in the early 90s. We might have read the whole thing, or just some excerpts. I think it was before English literature came under the National Curriculum, so it could have been simply a favourite of that school or teacher, but it's likely to have been a classic.
the main character started at a new school, possibly a boarding school, probably around the Industrial Revolution. All the other children were described as having piggy eyes and a cruel outlook, delighting in watching others fail and/or get punished. There was some mention of him not wanting to end up like them.
At one point the main character was viciously beaten by a teacher, and thought the teacher was trying to break his spirit. After the beating, he had enough strength to stand up and look the teacher in the eye. Afterwards that teacher showed him more respect and he realised that, instead of the teacher breaking him, he had broken the teacher.
